# Add a number to a list item with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

This is the DynamoDB table structure I'm working on:

```
{
  "userId": "99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999",
  "userProfile": {
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "1234124",
    "lastName": "123423",
  },
  "masterCards": [  
    {
      "cardId": 101000000000001,
      "cardImage": "logo.png",
      "cardName": "VipCard1",
      "cardWallet": "0xFDB17d12057b6Fe8c8c425D2DB88d8475674567"
    },
    {
      "cardId": 102000000000002,
      "cardImage": "logo.png",
      "cardName": "VipCard2",
      "cardWallet": "0xFDB17d12057b6Fe8c8c425D2DB88d8183454345"
    },
    {
      "cardId": 103000000000003,
      "cardImage": "logo.png",
      "cardName": "VipCard3",
      "cardWallet": "0xFDB17d12057b6Fe8c8c425D2DB88d8184345345"
    }
  ],

}
```

I'm trying to increase the `cardId` field by one for the first list item with this Lambda function:

```
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'eu-central-1', apiVersion:'2012-08-10'});
const counterId="99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999"

        const params = {
                TableName:"FidelityCardsUsers",
                Key: {"userId":{"S":counterId}},
                UpdateExpression:"ADD #masterCards[0].#cardId :increment",
                ExpressionAttributeNames:{
                    "#masterCards": "masterCards",
                    "#cardId": "cardId"
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues:{":increment": {"N": "1"}}
            }

        dynamoDB.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {

                        if (err) {
                            console.log('error getting counter from DynamDB: ',err)
                            callback(err);
                        } else {
                            callback(null,data)

                          }

  })
```

In return I get only a new top-level attribute named `"mastercards[0].cardId[0]"` with a value number set to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to increment In an array and its work fine with `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()`

Example :

var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

```
let params = {
  TableName:'tableName',
  Key: {
    'venueId': 'VENUE_002'
  },
  UpdateExpression: "ADD #walk.#coordinates[0] :increment",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#walk': 'walk',
    '#coordinates': 'coordinates'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':increment': 1 // This is from the client
  },
  ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
};
docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('failure:updateShuttleDirection:failed');
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('success:updateShuttleDirection:complete');
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Sample Data:

```
"walk": {
      "coordinates": [
       10,
       20
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
```

> I have tried to increment 10 to 11 and its work fine

Comment: definitely `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();` is the way to go, btw how do you get back the new "counter"? because the data value seems empty.

Comment: Use `ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'` in query. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html), it seems that:

> the ADD action can only be used on top-level attributes, not nested
>   attributes.